# How are Azure Event Hub event properties serialized?

Tags: azure, azure-eventhub

I want to produce and send `EventData` objects that have various application-specific properties set in the [EventData.Properties](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.azure.eventhubs.eventdata.properties?view=azure-dotnet#Microsoft_Azure_EventHubs_EventData_Properties) dictionary. The `Properties` dictionary itself is defined as `IDictionary<string, object>` which means I can pass any data type as the value.

```cs
var eventData = new EventData(bytes);
eventData.Properties["Prop1"] = // string?
eventData.Properties["Prop2"] = // int?
eventData.Properties["Prop3"] = // DateTime?
eventData.Properties["Prop4"] = // Custom?
```

What data types am I *actually* allowed to pass into the `Properties` dictionary? Obviously this data needs to be serialized somehow, but the documentation does not mention anything about this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found more information by trying something that didn't work, and then finding the source code by looking at the exception call-stack.

In my case, the supported property types seems to be derived from what the AMQP protocol supports (which is documented [here](http://docs.oasis-open.org/amqp/core/v1.0/os/amqp-core-types-v1.0-os.html)). There is actually a big switch statement in the internal `AmqpMessageConverter` code which basically gives me my answer:

[AmqpMessageConverter.TryGetAmqpObjectFromNetObject](https://github.com/Azure/azure-service-bus-dotnet/blob/6f144e91310dcc7bd37aba4e8aebd535d13fa31a/src/Microsoft.Azure.ServiceBus/Amqp/AmqpMessageConverter.cs#L469-L530)

To summarize here:

- All .NET primitive types (`int`, `string`, `double`, etc.)
- `Guid`
- `DateTime` and `DateTimeOffset`
- `Stream`
- `Uri`
- `TimeSpan`
- `byte[]`
- `IList`
- `IDictionary`

My own custom type (a POCO - "Plain old CLR object") did was NOT accepted, and resulted in the following exception:

```
System.Runtime.Serialization.SerializationException: Serialization operation failed due to unsupported type EventHubsTesting.Program+Poco.
   at Microsoft.Azure.EventHubs.Amqp.AmqpMessageConverter.TryGetAmqpObjectFromNetObject(Object netObject, MappingType mappingType, Object& amqpObject)
   at Microsoft.Azure.EventHubs.Amqp.AmqpMessageConverter.UpdateAmqpMessageHeadersAndProperties(AmqpMessage message, String publisher, EventData eventData, Boolean copyUserProperties)
   at Microsoft.Azure.EventHubs.Amqp.AmqpMessageConverter.EventDataToAmqpMessage(EventData eventData)
   at Microsoft.Azure.EventHubs.Amqp.AmqpMessageConverter.EventDatasToAmqpMessage(IEnumerable`1 eventDatas, String partitionKey)
   at Microsoft.Azure.EventHubs.Amqp.AmqpEventDataSender.OnSendAsync(IEnumerable`1 eventDatas, String partitionKey)
   at Microsoft.Azure.EventHubs.EventDataSender.SendAsync(IEnumerable`1 eventDatas, String partitionKey)
   at Microsoft.Azure.EventHubs.EventHubClient.SendAsync(IEnumerable`1 eventDatas, String partitionKey)
   at EventHubsTesting.Program.Sender(CancellationTokenSource shutdownSource) in C:\EventHubsTesting\Program.cs:line 99
```

I assume that if I want to use custom types, then I'd need to serialize them myself before assigning them as application properties.

Comment: This is essentially what we figured out by trial and error as well. We just strip the important things other domains care about off of the POCO, throw them on the dictionary, and rely on subscribers to call for the entire POCO. Thanks for posting this answer, though!

Comment: Note that IList and IDictionary are not supported in UserProperties on Microsoft.Azure.ServiceBus.Message. The AmqpMessageConverter.TryGetAmqpObjectFromNetObject throws an exception if the incoming parameter mappingType == MappingType.ApplicationProperty.

The mappingType is MappingType.ApplicationProperty if it is the UserProperties that are being converted.

I would assume this is also the case for EventData.Properties.

Answer (score 1):

Following up on Chris's answer - AMQP headers are serialized according to the AMQP type spec - http://docs.oasis-open.org/amqp/core/v1.0/os/amqp-core-types-v1.0-os.html.

For any Java developers viewing this answer - you can use the Apache qpid library to perform encode/decode operations.  The decoder class can be found here - https://qpid.apache.org/releases/qpid-proton-j-0.33.1/api/index.html.

EH service is encoding-agnostic, so a consumer reading via Kafka protocol will need to manually decode AMQP headers.  Native EH clients will decode the headers for you.  See - https://github.com/Azure/azure-event-hubs-for-kafka/issues/56.